# Is it possible to only pick the properties that were explicitly defined in an interface which extends Record<string, unknown>?

Tags: typescript

The following interface from `next-auth/jwt`

```
export interface DefaultJWT extends Record<string, unknown> {
  name?: string | null
  email?: string | null
  picture?: string | null
  sub?: string
}

export interface JWT extends Record<string, unknown>, DefaultJWT {}
```

I'm trying to only pick the explicitly defined properties (`name`, `email`, `picture`, and `sub`).

```
import { JWT } from 'next-auth/jwt'

export interface DefaultMyJWT {
    user_id: string
    user_role: string
    org_id: string
    org_slug: string
}

export type MyJwt = Pick<JWT, keyof JWT> & DefaultMyJWT
```

But that produces a type that is pretty much exacly `JWT`. Which makes sense, because `keyof JWT` in this case is essentially `keyof string`.

I could do this

```
export type MyJwt = Pick<JWT, 'name' | 'email' | 'picture' | 'sub'> & DefaultMyJWT
```

However, this approach has the disadvantage that if the package that manages the type makes any changes, I have to be aware of this and alter my code accordingly after updating, and TypeScript linter won't be able to catch it.

Comment: You can use the `RemoveIndex` or `KnownKeys` utility types from the answer to the linked question.